# \if@onecolumn doesn't work

Tags: conditionals, ieeetran

I am using IEEEtran template. I wanted to adjust pictures or tables flexibly according to the column setting, so I wrote this:

`\resizebox{\if@onecolumn 0.75\columnwidth \else \columnwidth \fi}{!}{blah,blah...}`

but it seems latex doesn't recognize the `\if@onecolumn`, and always adapt my figures or tables into columnwidth.

At the beginning of my .tex file I use,

```
\documentclass[journal,a4paper,9pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
```

Does anyone have experience on this?

Comment: you don't give many clues but if you used that code in the document where `@` is not a letter then that is `\if @o ...` and tests if `@` is the same as `o` which will be false always.

Comment: You need to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around any macro that contains an `@` in its name, unless you are within an .sty-file.

Comment: What makes you think that `\if@onecolumn` is defined?

Answer (score 1):

The `IEEEtran` class does not define an `\if@onecolumn` conditional (didn't you get an undefined command error?)  It does however define `\ifCLASSOPTIONonecolumn`
so you can do

```
\resizebox{\ifCLASSOPTIONonecolumn 0.75\columnwidth \else \columnwidth \fi}{!}
```